# I have 2 texts, list and grid.it will show list to grid when i click but i want to show the previous text again when i click on it .How to do that?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Initially I setted the text as list in use-state and it change to grid when I click on it.How to show the list again when I click?

```
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('List');
```

```
function handleClick() {
    setButtonText('Grid');

};
```

This is the use-state and the function that changes the text.Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call same method and use ternary operator (check your current state and setState according to it).

```
function handleClick() {
  setButtonText(buttonText == 'Grid' ? 'List' : 'Grid');
};
```